How to accurately cut background and main object out from an image using masking method?
I have a image with the main object as the muffin and a dark background.
Using a mask image, I wanted to get 2 different images, 1 for the background without the muffin, and another is the muffin without the background separately.
the image
the mask image
I will describe the steps I created and the problems I faced for now below:
Step1: I discovered the mask image I gotten has bits of gray pixels along the edges of the muffin.
So I run the command below to "clean" the mask image to make sure all black is black.
convert mask.png -fuzz 100% -fill black -opaque black maskresult.png
Step2: Similar command as Step1, make sure non-black is all white
convert maskresult.png -fuzz 100% -fill white -opaque white -threshold 50% maskresult2.png
Step3: Cut the background out. I can see some of the muffin edges. I guess the problem lies on the mask image. Can we clean the edges or somehow "blur" the edge to make it less obvious?
composite -compose minus maskresult2.png test.jpg maskresult3.png
maskresult3.png
Step4: Invert the mask image to cut the muffin out, white into black, black into white.
convert maskresult2.png -negate maskresult4.png
maskresult4.png
Stpe5: Cut the muffin out
composite -compose minus maskresult4.png test.jpg maskresult5.png
maskresult5.png
Step6: Convert muffin background into transparent. This creates problems of black pixels within the muffin into transparent as well. If we zoom in closely into edges of the muffin, we will see bits of transparent pixel here and there, and the muffin edges is not smooth too.
convert maskresult5.png -fuzz 0% -transparent black maskresult6.png
maskresult6.png
I need advices on how can I,

Step3 and Step6 turning the "black" into transparent without affecting the background and the muffin?

Step3, cleaning the muffin edges to make it less obvious


Thank you very much!

Posting updated GM Commands to reflect the changes I made.
Step 1: clean the mask image, make sure black is all black, white is all white
convert mask.png -fuzz 100% -threshold 50% maskresult.png

Step2: turn mask image white into transparent to prepare background cutout.
convert maskresult.png -fuzz 100% -transparent white -blur 0x2 maskresult2.png

Step 3: cut the background
composite -compose copyopacity maskresult2.png test.jpg maskresult3.png

Step 4: invert the mask image, white into black, black into white, white into transparent + blur to soften the muffin edges
convert maskresult.png -negate -fuzz 100% -transparent white -blur 0x2 maskresult4.png

Step 5: cut the muffin
composite -compose copyopacity maskresult4.png test.jpg maskresult6.png

maskresult6
Because of the added "blur" to the mask image, the cut out background and the muffin will have slight fade out gray shadows along the edges of the muffin cut out.
Is it possible to get rid the unwanted shadows on the background and muffin?
comparison between results now and preferred result

This command uses one ImagMagick command to produce two output images, one with just the muffin on a transparent background, and one with just the background and a transparent hole where the muffin was.
convert muffin.jpg -background none null: ^
   ( muffmask.png -blur 0x1 ) ( +clone -negate ) ^
   -compose copyopacity -layers composite muffin-%02d.png

It starts by reading in the original input image. Then in parentheses, so it doesn't affect the input image, it reads in the mask image and blurs it a bit to soften the edges in the result. Then in parentheses again it makes a clone of that blurred mask, and swaps its black and white with "-negate".
With IM's special placeholder image "null:" between the input image and the two versions of the mask, it uses the operation "-layers composite" to apply each mask to the single input image, and create the two separate output images, the muffin and the background.
The compose method "copyopacity" uses a grayscale image as an alpha mask to create transparent areas.
The output files will be named "muffin-00.png" and "muffin-01.png".
The command is in Windows CLI syntax. For a *nix OS you will probably need to change the continued-line carets "^" to backslashes "\" and escape the parentheses with backslashes "\(...\)".

Thanks for your help, I took examples of your IM commands inspirations and convert them into GM commands. It works! However I'm stuck with the final problem.
The problem lies on the "-blur" effect applied to the mask image which causes the end result muffin image to have "shadows" effects which I can't seem to get rid of.
I will appreciate if you can advise me further on how can I get rid the unwanted "shadow" on the end result.

Updating my progress, I installed IM into my machine and run your commands to create both the mask images and end results to decipher and compare to GM. I had successfully recreate the exact same mask and end images using GM by following your IM commands. I will post the my GM answer below. Once again thank you very much @GeeMack

Below is the solution I resolved by GM commands. Unlike IM, there are multiple commands to run separately:
Step 1: clean the mask image, make sure black is all black, white is all white.
convert mask.png -fuzz 100% -threshold 50% maskresult.png

Step 2: add blur to the cleaned mask image using 3x1 parameter which I find its the optimal for my image.
convert maskresult.png -blur 3x1 maskresult2.png

Step 3: Using background as transparent, cut the muffin out.
composite -background none -compose copyopacity maskresult2.png test.jpg maskresult3.png

Step 4: Invert the cleaned mask image and add the same blur parameter
convert maskresult.png -negate -blur 3x1 maskresult10.png

Step 5: Using background as transparent, cut the background out.
composite -background none -compose copyopacity maskresult10.png test.jpg maskresult11.png

GM - Muffin image cutout
GM - Background image cutout
IM - Muffin image cutout
IM - Background image cutout
